# Setting a data/spend limit for Looker Studio user with @DS_USER_EMAIL parameter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We estimate Looker Studio reports spend by user independently.

In order to limit excessive quering through dashboards users, I added below to the original `BigQuery Custom SQL` source.

```sql
with check_user as (
 select
   case when count(*) then true else false and as continue_query
 from ((
   select
     looker_user,
     allowed                    --flag that is true if user allowed to query
   from `user_spend`
   where looker_user = @DS_USER_EMAIL
 )
 union distinct (
   select @DS_USER_EMAIL, true  --always-true for new users that haven't appeared in our tracking
 ))
)

select * from table1            --original custom query
cross join check_user
where check_user.continue_query = true
```

1. Is there a better way to achieve the same effect -> discourage dashboard users to query more?
2. How could I also prevent BigQuery billing by the disallowed Looker Studio users? Currently, they receive empty results, but query is still executed againt BigQuery and charged.